# How to sort this jQuery element to this

Tags: jquery

I want to make id="a" element div to be the second div in the div.b element. 
And I want to how to make id="a" element div to be the last div in the div.b element.

Here is the code:

```
<div class='b'>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div id="a">I want to moderate this div </div>
    <div>a</div>
</div>
```

The result I want to achieve is:

```
<div class='b'>
    <div>a</div>
    <div id="a">I want to moderate this div</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
</div>
```

And:

```
<div class='b'>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div id="a">I want to moderate this div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many question you have with this same html and what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function will insert content *after* what's selected.

```
$("div.b div:first").after($("#a"));
```

This selects the first div under your `<div class="b"`, then inserts your `<div id="a"` after *that*, thereby making `a` the second div under `b`.

To make `a` be the last div under `b`, you'd find the currently last div under `b`, and insert `a` after *that*

```
$("div.b div:last").after($("#a"));
```

To make `a` first, you'd use the [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) function:

```
$("div.b div:first").before($("#a"));
```

Finally, per mu's good comment, I'll mention the [eq function](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), which would allow you to select a child div of any index

```
$("div.b div:eq(2)").after($("#a"));
```

So now `a` would be third.

Comment: .after and .before actually move an existing element?  I've always assumed they were for inserting new / unattached objects into the DOM.

Comment: @Jake - yes, it moves them.  From the docs: `If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved rather than cloned`

Comment: Might be word mentioning the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector while you're here.

Comment: @muistooshort - (great user name) - thank you, I added it, and it definitely makes the answer more complete

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

  var id = $("#id");

  id.detach();

  id.insertAfter("div.b div:first"); // or "div.b div:last"

});
```